# Check not null and greater than with c# 7.3 using "is" operator

Tags: c#, c#-7.3

In latest version of c# you can check not null with `is not`.

I am using 7.3 version, How can I use `is` operator to check not null

Comment: `is object` was considered the canonical non-null check in 7.3. https://twitter.com/jaredpar/status/1115019017297596416

Comment: You cannot. C# 7 pattern matching was pretty much a MVP. `not` is C# 9 thing and the workarounds for not null checks prior to that are not exactly expressive. Probably just use `x != null` like we did all the years prior to pattern matching. The reference equality semantics avoiding `Equals` virt call can be achieved with `!ReferenceEquals(x, null)` although this is very rarely needed unless perf is a significant concern.

Comment: I'm guessing there's a specific reason no one has said this, but why can't you just use `object != null`?

Comment: @Pow strictly speaking, that doesn't have the same meaning - in particular, `!= null` has a different meaning depending on whether the type has a custom non-equality operator (`op_Inequality`), where-as `is not null`, `is object` and `is {}` are always strictly a pure null check

Comment: @Pow example: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwAEAmARgFgAoagNwEMoACBJgXibxgHcmAxCBAAUASgDc1ImQCcQ1gEIOeHABsV4yTLlMAlgGdOEDJ1XqJNKg2YBPdpx5MAQo1Hmps24pNqNVd0Nt9Q2NlH3NJEn5BagBvaiYEpiIAZiSyJCZgQRUmCAAHGCh6DGh2NiEBCBY0KKrrEXjEuKpE1rTZACJKkCYwHD0SgFsyjt82xKIAdiYAJRgAM0KYPDAYAFEARxx6FT05NHrzVoBfakaElLSMrIgc/MLi0sUKwWrapnrzpmbxi60uwQ9PoDCDDRSjI6/KZMeRzRawFbrLY7PYIA5jRKnKhY0hORjfY5AA===

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the C# 7.3 restriction here is because you're targeting .NET Framework; however, this C# 7.3 version is only the *default* language version. The compiler and runtime are separate and while there are *some* dependencies (on API shapes and even runtime features), most language features *do not depend at all* on the runtime. This is one of those cases. So: edit your csproj file, and add (or edit):

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion>12</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Now you can use features up to and including C# 12 (assuming you have an up-to-date compiler).

Comment: I use framework 4.6.1 and for that i can use v7.3, can't I?

Comment: @Ankita you can use C# 12 for that just fine, by doing as shown above. There are some language features that need features you won't have, but: the compiler will tell you. This language feature: doesn't need anything.